# Javascript not executing from ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, .net, registerstartupscript

Please look at this code and find out why it isnt working. I am not getting an alert in the webpage. But, the console.writeLine beneath it is getting executed.

```
    private void PublishLoop()
    {
        while (Running)
        {          
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            dtMessages = (String)(Cache.Get(key));
            if (dtMessages == null)
            {
                //publish here
                dtMessages = LoadMessages();
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0,null,dtMessages);
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"ClientScript", "alert('hi');",true);
                Console.WriteLine(dtMessages);
            }
        }

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** You can actually only register one unique *key* per response. You're running this line of code inside a while loop, so it keeps registering the same key. You need to give it a unique *key* parameter each time you call this function. In your case, maybe you can have a counter in your loop and append it to your key string

```
int i = 0;
while (Running)
        {          
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            dtMessages = (String)(Cache.Get(key));
            if (dtMessages == null)
            {
                //publish here
                dtMessages = LoadMessages();
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0,null,dtMessages);
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"ClientScript" + i.ToString(), "alert('hi');",true);
                Console.WriteLine(dtMessages);
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nope. It still doesn't work. I have this in my code behind file and i launch the aspx file in the browser. I can see the console.writeline output in Visual studio. But,i am not getting the alert in my web browser

Comment: BTW, however many times your alert() script gets registered is how many alert() msg's you're going to receive, you know that right? If you only want this to happen once, you should only call it once

Comment: It still doesnt work. This is weird ... I dont know where its going wrong . :(

Comment: @hari Are you doing calling code this code from the aspx code behind file? Or somewhere else? If it is code behind, try calling the function one time outside of the while loop and see if you can get that to work, then go from there

Comment: Its not working without the while loop also :( .. also, yes,i am calling this code from the aspx code behind file only

Comment: @Nicklamort let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1063/discussion-between-hari-and-nicklamort)